# SystemVerilog Merging Events

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was reading about SV Merging events from this [website](https://verificationguide.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-events/). The code is as follows:

```
module events_ex;

  event ev_1; //declaring event ev_1
 
  initial begin
    fork
      //process-1, triggers the event
      begin
        #40;
        $display($time,"\tTriggering The Event");
        ->ev_1;
      end
     
      //process-2, wait for the event to trigger
      begin
        $display($time,"\tWaiting for the Event to trigger");
        #60;
        @(ev_1.triggered);
        $display($time,"\tEvent triggered");
      end
    join
  end
  initial begin
    #100;
    $display($time,"\tEnding the Simulation");
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

The result for the same is:

```
0  Waiting for the Event to trigger
40  Triggering The Event
100 Ending the Simulation
```

In this particular code, the trigger is being executed first at `40 time units`, then the waiting is applied at `60 time units`. It is known that, if the trigger executes first, then the waiting process remains blocked. If I use `#60 wait(ev_1.triggered);` in the `line 17` this can be resolved. However, it is still showing the same result? I want to know the concept behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanism is pretty simple: value of `event.triggered` is only set in the same simulation tick as when it was triggered. It is not sticky and becomes 0 in the next tick.

> It is known that, if the trigger executes first, then the waiting process remains blocked.

Yes, because the unblocking event has already passed and #60 is too late for it to be detected. So, it cannot be detected any longer neither by `@` nor by `wait`.

Now, what you can do is to set a sticky variable at the event, for example as `triggered` in the following:

```
module events_ex;

  event ev_1; //declaring event ev_1
  logic triggered = 1'b0;
  
  initial begin
    fork
      //process-1, triggers the event
      begin
        #40;
        $display($time,"\tTriggering The Event");
        ->ev_1;
      end
     
      begin 
        @(ev_1)
        triggered = 1'b1; // << set the sticky var
      end
      
      //process-2, wait for the event to trigger
      begin
        $display($time,"\tWaiting for the Event to trigger");
        #60;
        wait(triggered); // << wait for sticky var value of 1
        $display($time, "\tEvent triggered");
      end
    join
  end
  

  initial begin
    #100;
    $display($time,"\tEnding the Simulation");
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

There however, you can see a difference in semantics between `@` and  `wait` operators. `@` waits for a change of the value, which happened at #40 and it will not be able to catch it at #60 as well. `wait` on the other hand, waits for a *level*, for *triggered* to become 1'b1. So, it will work here since the sticky var has been already set.

Answer (score 1):

The example on that website is not very good. You would never want to use `@` with the `triggered` method.

When you *trigger* an event with `-> ev_1` or `->> ev_1`, The `triggered` method of that event is only valid from moment of the trigger (or NBA region of the trigger for `->>`) until the end of the time step.

The `@ev_1` must be executed *before* the moment of the trigger. Otherwise it has to wait for the next trigger.

The `wait(ev_1.triggered())` construct is only useful if it gets executed *before* the trigger, OR within the same timestep and there is potential race condition between the point of trigger AND waiting for that trigger.

Using raw events is not something I would recommend for most users. There are usually more software like mechanisms to achieve the same thing.